# where in no result in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

hey i have problem with `where in` in doctrine and i search and query is exactly like this but it result always is empty. `where in` not works . what is the problem?

```
$qb = $this->connection->getQueryBuilder();
        $users = ['admin'];
        $result = $qb->select("*")
            ->from("users")
            ->where("groles IN (:groles)")
            ->setParameter('groles', $users)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

//....

->setParameter('groles', $users, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
```

Comment: thanks you saved my day. what is the point of it?

Comment: Doctrine ussualy try to infers this param, but for any reason is not working for you (maybe you have an old version, who knows). If you want to investigate more you can debug the class Doctrine\ORM\Query\ParameterTypeInferer and find out why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).